# WPF : How can i show my login window(project imported) before my application window?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, authentication

I have made a project for a login WPF application that basically performs a database connection. Now I am developing an application (always in WPF) that need this login project to start. I have added the Login.Exe to the reference in my current project, but I can't find a way to force the start with the login and only after that run my MainWindow().

I'm currently trying something like this

```
namespace Administrator
{ 
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Window login = new Login.MainWindow();
            login.Show();
        }
    }
}
```

My mainwindow.xaml has empty content, and this piece of code it shows the login form, but also a blank window. How can I achieve my goal?

Comment: Is the login window a `Window` or a `UserControl`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can achieve this with the following pattern.

In your App.xaml change `StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml"` to `Startup="ApplicationStart"` and in your App.xaml.cs create the method ApplicationStart.

```
private void ApplicationStart(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
{
    Window login = new Login.MainWindow();
    login.Show();

    // Determine if login was successful
    if (login.DataContext is LoginViewModel loginVM)
    {
        if (!loginVM.LoginSuccessful)
        {
            // handle any cleanup and close/shutdown app
        }
    }

    //show your MainWindow
}
```

I prefere this pattern because you can e.g. setup your DI container in the ApplicationStart or anything else you want to before your main view is shown.

Comment: Your welcome :) Would be nice if you accept the answer when it's working.

Comment: Now just another question. Since my login project was developed following MVVM pattern, and i need a variable from it, is it correct to access to the Login VM using something like: VMinstance = login.Datacontext as ViewModel ?

Comment: Good question and there are different solutions. Maybe there are cleaner solutions but I would do it like you and use the ViewModel to get the data.

Answer (score 6):

Set in the App.xaml the "ShutdownMode" and the "StartupUri":

```
   <Application x:Class="MyApp.App"
                xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyApp"
                ShutdownMode="OnExplicitShutdown"
                StartupUri="Login.xaml">
```

The "StartupUri" is your login form.

Comment: Possible as well but in my opinion it's not the cleanest way of programming when your login window has to open your main window. That logic depends not in the login window. That's why I prefere the ApplicationStart method (like in my answer shown).